# Where does NetServerEnum get its list of machines from?

Tags: c#, networking, netapi32

Where does `NetServerEnum()` get its list of machines from?

Does it use the computer browser service or will it use AD as a preference if AD is available?

Links:

- [NetServerEnum on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370623(VS.85).aspx)
- [NetServerEnum on PInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32/netserverenum.html)
- [Decription of the Computer Browser Service](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/188001)

Comment: One thing you could do is to run something like WireShark and see if you can determine what sort of traffic is being initiated when NetServerEnum is called. I suspect it is just going against AD in which case you will probably see LDAP queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Browser service. NetServerEnum pre-dates Active Directory, and has to run on non-AD systems. NetServerEnum will return 6118 (no browsers) if it can't find a browse server. I think AD has the ADSI interface for this kind of task, but I never programmed against AD.

Note that NetServerEnum can be unconscionably slow on a large domain: I found this out the hard way by trying to use NSE for a rudimentary "discovery" algorithm. Soon learned my lesson and swapped to UDP for that task.

Comment: Hi Bob, I'm having the same problem with the NetServerEnum function stalling. When you say you've used UDP instead, how exactly did you use the protocol? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Broadcast a (small) UDP packet using sendto with INADDR_BROADCAST when you start up. In the ping message, put the originator's data such as IP address. Do it (slowly) several times because UDP is unreliable. If the rxr has no current TCP connection to the originator, when it receives a ping it tries to connect back via TCP. NB: won't work across a router: you need to maintain your own IP connection list for that case. Can't post code, it belongs to my employer. Note: under IPv6 there's no equivalent, you need multicast for that.